# Spring batch hangs after partitioning

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-batch

I am dealing with 2 million records and grid size of 20 for my spring batch application. For 100-200k records it works fine, but for 2 million it fails after partitioning.

Partition info:

```
{
    partition - 20 = {
        startKey = 1980865.0,
        endKey = 2069192.0,
        partitionSize = 72,
        partitionId = 20,
        partitionRecordCount = 88328
    },
    partition - 10 = {
        st
        artKey = 938305.0,
        endKey = 1042560.0,
        partitionSize = 72,
        partitionId = 10,
        partitionRecordCount = 104256
    },
    partition - 11 = {
        startKey = 1042561.0,
        endKey = 1146816.0,
        partitionSize = 72,
        partitionId = 11,
        partitionRecordCount = 104256
    },
    partition - 12 = {
        startKey = 1146817.0,
        endKey = 1251072.0,
        partitionSize = 72,
        partitionId = 12,
        partitionRecordCount = 104256
    },
    partition - 13 = {
        startKey = 1251073.0,
        endKey = 1355328.0,
        partitionSize = 72,
        partitionId = 13,
        partitionRecordCount = 104256
    },
    par
    tition - 14 = {
        startKey = 1355329.0,
        endKey = 1459584.0,
        partitionSize = 72,
        partitionId = 14,
        partitionRecordCount = 104256
    },
    partition - 15 = {
        startKey = 1459585.0,
        end
        Key = 1563840.0,
        partitionSize = 72,
        partitionId = 15,
        partitionRecordCount = 104256
    },
    partition - 16 = {
        startKey = 1563841.0,
        endKey = 1668096.0,
        partitionSize = 72,
        p
        artitionId = 16,
        partitionRecordCount = 104256
    },
    partition - 17 = {
        startKey = 1668097.0,
        endKey = 1772352.0,
        partitionSize = 72,
        partitionId = 17,
        partitionRecordCoun
        t = 104256
    },
    partition - 18 = {
        startKey = 1772353.0,
        endKey = 1876608.0,
        partitionSize = 72,
        partitionId = 18,
        partitionRecordCount = 104256
    },
    partition - 19 = {
        startKey =
            1876609.0,
        endKey = 1980864.0,
        partitionSize = 72,
        partitionId = 19,
        partitionRecordCount = 104256
    },
    partition - 1 = {
        startKey = 1.0,
        endKey = 104256.0,
        partitionSize
             = 72,
        partitionId = 1,
        partitionRecordCount = 104256
    },
    partition - 2 = {
        startKey = 104257.0,
        endKey = 208512.0,
        partitionSize = 72,
        partitionId = 2,
        partitionRecordCou
        nt = 104256
    },
    partition - 3 = {
        startKey = 208513.0,
        endKey = 312768.0,
        partitionSize = 72,
        partitionId = 3,
        partitionRecordCount = 104256
    },
    partition - 4 = {
        startKey = 3127
            69.0,
        endKey = 417024.0,
        partitionSize = 72,
        partitionId = 4,
        partitionRecordCount = 104256
    },
    partition - 5 = {
        startKey = 417025.0,
        endKey = 521280.0,
        partitionSize = 7
            2,
        partitionId = 5,
        partitionRecordCount = 104256
    },
    partition - 6 = {
        startKey = 521281.0,
        endKey = 625536.0,
        partitionSize = 72,
        partitionId = 6,
        partitionRecordCount
             = 104256
    },
    partition - 7 = {
        startKey = 625537.0,
        endKey = 729792.0,
        partitionSize = 72,
        partitionId = 7,
        partitionRecordCount = 104256
    },
    partition - 8 = {
        startKey = 729793
            .0,
        endKey = 834048.0,
        partitionSize = 72,
        partitionId = 8,
        partitionRecordCount = 104256
    },
    partition - 9 = {
        startKey = 834049.0,
        endKey = 938304.0,
        partitionSize = 72,
        partitionId = 9,
        partitionRecordCount = 104256
    }
}
Total no. of Partitions: 20
```

the last log it prints is the partition created and then control never comes into writer. For 200k records it was struggling, so I increased the connection pool size, which fixed the issue but it fails for 2 million rows.

There is no error, just it hangs there.

Comment: For 20 partitions?  Have you profiled the app?  What is it hanging on?  I know there used to be an issue with how the step executions were stored in the job repository when using a large number of partitions that caused an app to look like it was hanging because they need to be stored before the workers can start.  That was fixed in a recent version though...

Comment: @MichaelMinella, I have not done profiling, but yes partitions were 20 earlier and later, i reduced them to 5. it still waits for 4-5 hours for writer to start writing a few files and then hangs or sometime breaks with 'communication link failure' error. this error though never comes with less data.

Comment: Got it working, the partition query was incorrect, plus, the file writing was not threaded.

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to db. Can you check if the application is able to access db with write credentials. I did notice this kind of issue where partitioning is done and the actual processing hung. After troubleshooting, realized it is not able to write to db. Once the db was fixed it ran fine.